# DataGrid CellEditingTemplate with a custom control does not fire validation errors on DataGrid level

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I am using a `DataGrid` and I have created a custom control named `Time_Edit`. This control is a complex control with two `TextBox` controls.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="Time_Edit">
     <local:TimeView DataContext="{Binding TimeViewModel}"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

`TimeViewModel` is a property of the main view model.

I added a `DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate`:

```
 <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Viewbox>
            <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2"
                ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                    Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                    FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </ControlTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The binding works correctly. The validation is performed on the `TextBox` control level but not on the `DataGridRow` level. Can someone help me?